# Multiple Secondary Sorts Based on First Sort

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting

I have a table with a few columns. I have sorted the 'number' column to be in order. However the harder part occurs, I would like to sort the 'Letter' and 'id' columns as secondary sort based on the first column. The 'name' column just follows the 'id' column without sorting.

I tried a few different query, including `ORDER BY number, letter, id`, but this obviously sorts the 'id' column relative to the 'Letter' column, which is not what I wanted. I also searched for other SQL clauses that might help me in sorting two independent columns, but so far most answers use the `ORDER BY` keyword.

The final result should look like this:

## **Before Sorting**

[image: Before Sorting]

## **Desired Result**

[image: After Sorting]

Both 'Letter' and 'id' are sorted independently as secondary sort, relative to the first ('number') column, while the 'name' just follows the 'id' column.

## **Edit:**

Some might say `ORDER BY number, letter, id` works, but actually each columns are sorted based on the previous sorted columns, instead of the first column. This is the result if the command is used.

[image]

Comment: with the desired Result, 'ORDER BY Number, Letter, id' seems good, can you give an example in which this wouldn't work ?

Comment: @DanielE. It will sort 'id' based on 'Letter', instead of 'Number' which is the desired result. I have edited the post to make it clearer for you.

Comment: `order by` sorts *rows*, but you want to sort *columns* independenly to create new rows? That's not how databases work, go back to Excel

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
order by number, id
```

Comment: How about the 'Letter' columns? I believe this only sorts the 'number' and 'id' columns?

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . A sensible answer to a sensible question.  However, if you look closely at the result set, you'll see that the values within each row change, so this answer isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to order the values in *columns*, not in *rows*.  That is strange, but can be done in SQL.  The idea is to enumerate by the ordered values in each column, and then join them together:

```
select tn.number, tn.letter, ti.id, ti.name
from (select t.*, (@rnl := @rnl + 1) as rn
      from (select t.* from t order by t.number, t.letter
           ) t cross join
           (select @rnl := 0) params
     ) tn join
     (select t.*, (@rni := @rni + 1) as rn
      from (select t.* from t order by t.number, t.id
           ) t cross join
           (select @rni := 0) params
     ) ti
     on tn.rn = ti.rn
order by tn.rn;
```

We can enumerate over the entire table (i.e. not taking `number` into account).  The subqueries are ordered by `number` first, so the `rn` values for a given `number` will always be in the same range.